# How to rename files with ordering using Bash {thisfile.jpg -> newfile1.jpg, thatfile.jpg -> newfile2.jpg}

Tags: bash, mv

Let's say I have 100 jpg files.

```
DSC_0001.jpg
DSC_0002.jpg
DSC_0003.jpg
....
DSC_0100.jpg
```

And I want to rename them like

```
summer_trip_1.jpg
summer_trip_2.jpg
summer_trip_3.jpg
.....
summer_trip_100.jpg
```

So I want these properties to be modified:
1. filename
2. order of the file(as the order by date files were created)

How could I achieve this by using bash? Like:

```
for file in *.jpg ; do mv blah blah blah ; done
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple: have a variable and increment it at each step.

Example:

```
cur_number=1
prefix="summer_trip_"
suffix=""
for file in *.jpg ; do
    echo mv "$file" "${prefix}${cur_number}${suffix}.jpg" ;
    let cur_number=$cur_number+1  # or :  cur_number=$(( $cur_number + 1 ))
done
```

and **once you think it's ready**, take out the `echo` to let the `mv` occur.

If you prefer them to be ordered by file date (usefull, for example, when mixing photos from several cameras, of if on yours the "numbers" rolled over):

change

```
for file in *.jpg ; do
```

into

```
for file in $( ls -1t *.jpg ) ; do
```

Note that that second example will only work *if* your original filenames don't have space (and other weird characters) in them, which is fine with almost all cameras I know about.

Finally, instead of `${cur_number}` you could use `$(printf '%04s' "${cur_number}")` so that the new number has leading zeros, making sorting much easier.

Comment: Thank you for your contribute, Olivier. I will check later in this evening or tomorrow and update the mark :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but nothing changed. It did echo my commands but file names are still the same. and if I command cur_number=$(( $cur_number + 1 )), instead of cur_number=$cur_number+1, the variable doesn't change and fixed the the final number of the variable.(f.i. if 5 loops then the variable is fixed to 5.)

Comment: My machine runs Mac OS X 10.6.9. Could it be a reason for this trouble?

Comment: Oh my God. I just embarrassed myself. I forgot to take out the "echo". Why did you put it in the script in the first place? I'm a newbie in CS world and I wonder if that is some convention while writing a script?

Comment: I made your commands as a script and it's now one of my DIY command on Mac OS. I could edit prefixes and suffixes in the script every time I want to rename files with new file names, but it would be awesome if I could give prefixes and suffixes as arguments when I run the command. Any suggestion Olivier?

Comment: for instance, the shell script name is "rename_jpg". So I would like to be able to command in Terminal like: User$ rename_jpg "prefix" "suffix"

Comment: @YOUNG:: it's simple. In your script, "$1" and "$2" will be the first and second parameters. Just have `prefix="$1" ; suffix="$2"` . And if you want also to give defaults values (in case one does not provide 2 parameters but only the first one or 0) : `prefix="${1:-default_value}" ; suffix="${2:-default_value_2}"` will allow this.

Comment: @YOUNG: about the "echo", it is usually a good idea to first test the script, make sure it will do the command correctly, and fix it until it does so. THEN you take out the "echo" to actually do the command (especially usefull for commands that change things, such as "mv" "rm" etc)

Comment: Olivier, I sincerely thank you for your perfect tips. It does its job and this is what I've wanted to realize for long time! It seems like you are an expert in the field. Could you recommend me some nice libraries or tutorials for shell scripting, please? I think I'm going to read one from Apple developer's documentations. Anyway big thanks from Helsinki! :D

Comment: @YOUNG: lol, thanks for the kind words, but I'm not as an expert in the field as is Stephane Chazelas, for example (see his answers!). I try to focus on readability (over terseness) and portability (over neatness). I'll give you some pointers for scripting. But for everything bash/shell related, I already highly recommend you read (maybe after a bit of scripting) the excellent material on http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ , http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls are 2 excellent reads (again, maybe after you already know scripting...)

Comment: @YOUNG: a good starting point seems to be: http://linuxcommand.org/index.php . The 2nd part (http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_writing_shell_scripts.php) is about scripting (but the 1st part, http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_learning_the_shell.php, about using the shell in day to day, is also nice, apparently). I do not know if they provide *only* portable (sh-compatible) advices, so maybe be careful that you may learn things that only work on linux or "recent" systems with GNU programs [many companies still use older environments where you only have "ancient" commands, and can get bitten easily!]

Comment: Usually the GNU equivalent of unix programs (ex: GNU ls, tar, cc, grep, find, etc.) add a lot of nice things [and options], + also correct some nasty unpleasantness. For example the primitive "tar" doesn't strip off the leading '/' from absolute filenames. So when extracting, it goes where the original file was [ex: /etc/hosts] instead of in the subdir you want it to go to... [ex: /my/subdir/etc/hosts]. You learn to be weary of this, when using an old production system! Therefore I always try to be careful and try to point those things out in my [and others] answers. Portability is king, imo.

Comment: Hei, Olivier! I'm so sorry for the late reply. I've been on my winter vacation from school and also from computer. Thank you so much for your super kind advices. The linuxcommand.org seems pretty beginner-friendly! Maybe I will start from there :) I appreciate your kindness and happy new year!!!

Comment: @YOUNG: Glad this helps :) Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `rename` ?

```
 rename DSC_ summer_trip_ *.jpg
```

See man page of [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename)

Comment: @user2719058 - Can you please elaborate ? If you are talking about the usage, do note that there are two flavors of rename's around, one a perl script written originally by Larry Wall and a binary version which is pre-installed in with linux. What I've is the later. Look at the man page for usage if you are not clear still.

Comment: Thank you for your contribute, dpp. I will check later in this evening or tomorrow and update the mark :)

Comment: @dpp Ah, you are right. On my Debian systems, the binary `rename` is installed as `rename.ul`, so I forgot about that. I reverted my downvote. You may want to consider adding that clarification to your answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

This works if your original numbers are all padded with zeroes to the same length:

```
i=0; for f in DSC_*.jpg; do mv "$f" "summer_trip_$((++i)).jpg"; done
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribute, user2719058. I will check later in this evening or tomorrow and update the mark :)

Comment: Thanks, but not all my files have systemic names :(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly:

> So I want these properties to be modified: 1. filename 2. order of the file(as the order by date files were created)

if numbers of renamed files shall increment in order by file creation date, then use the following for loop:

```
for file in $(ls -t -r *.jpg); do
```

-t sorts by mtime (last modification time, not exactly creation time, newest first) and -r reverses the order listing oldest first. Just in case if original .jpg file numbers are not in the same order as pictures were taken.
As it was mentioned previously, this won't work if file names have whitespaces. If your files have spaces please try modifying IFS variable before for loop:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

It will force split of 'ls' command results on newlines only (not whitespaces). Also it would fail if there is a newline in a file name (rather exotic IMHO :). Changing IFS may have some subtle effects further in your script, so you can save old one and restore after the loop.

Comment: Your command line doesn't work with files whose names include whitespaces. Check out Olivier's post.

Comment: That's a good point. I was aware of Olivier's comment but if your files have whitespaces, then yes, it won't work. Edited the answer a bit. Setting IFS shall do the trick. Just I don't have Mac OSX to test and assume bash on Mac uses \n for newline separator (not \r).